# Why is a `std::remove_cv<_Iter>::type` not a type?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20

I have two versions of the what I'd expect to be the same function but gcc says version 1 is valid while version 2 gives a

```
expected a type, got 'std::remove_cv<_Iter>::type'
```

I don't quite understand this error, as I'd expect that the `using` statement required a type, and wouldn't automatically promote a `'std::remove_cv<_Iter>::type'` to something else?

Can somebody explain whats going on here?

```
template<typename U,typename V> constexpr inline auto is_same_rcv() noexcept
{
    //version 1 works
    using u_underlying = std::remove_cv<U>::type;
    using v_underlying = std::remove_cv<V>::type;
    return std::is_same<u_underlying,v_underlying>::value;
}
```

and

```
template<typename U,typename V> constexpr inline auto is_same_rcv() noexcept
{
    //version 2 doesn't work
    using u_underlying = std::remove_cv<U>::type;
    return std::is_same<u_underlying,std::remove_cv<V>::type>::value;
}
```

Associated [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9rf8PK)

Edit for fun, it looks like clang and gcc different on the interpretation of the using keyword (see https://godbolt.org/z/P9Pcn6)

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe, without `typename`, the language assumes `std::remove_cv<U>::type` is a value.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm, the dupe isn't very obvious. Where would typename go (its already in the signature) and why does `using` work but not when its part of the template...

Comment: The `typename` always prefixes the name, so `using u_underlying = typename std::remove_cv<U>::type;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Or rather should be `return std::is_same<u_underlying,typename std::remove_cv<V>::type>::value;`

Comment: I reopened the question because it seems to be focused on the difference between the usage of `typename` in `using` statement and `return` statement.

Comment: FYI, Clang gives a [very readable error](https://godbolt.org/z/7P889E) for this case. C++20 also allows elision of `typename` for the type aliases where a type is the only allowable thing that can be there. Offhand, I don't think it did the same for type arguments because it requires semantic analysis. (It seems Clang doesn't implement said change yet, so I added a couple `typename`s to focus on the relevant error message.)

Comment: @chris Looks like clang and gcc differ on this one https://godbolt.org/z/P9Pcn6 ! Oh no!

Comment: Well, yes, I mentioned Clang appears not to support the change yet (C++20 is quite new after all). The point was rather that different compilers excel in different areas. Particularly when it comes to confusing errors, it's worth checking multiple compilers once the effort required to do so is sufficiently low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the keyword [`typename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) to tell that the [dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) `std::remove_cv<V>::type` is a type.

```
return std::is_same<u_underlying, typename std::remove_cv<V>::type>::value;
//                                ^^^^^^^^
```

In the `using` statement `typename` is not needed again since C++20.

> In some contexts, only type names can validly appear. In these
> contexts, a dependent qualified name is assumed to name a type and no
> `typename` is required:
>
> - ...
> - A qualified name that appears in [*type-id*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_naming), where the smallest enclosing *type-id* is:
>
>   - ...
>   - the *type-id* in an [alias declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias);
>   - ...

Comment: Hmm, it seems that clang still requires it. Maybe thats missing functionality?

Comment: @Mikhail I think clang is just still not implementing the new feature.

Comment: Clang has not implemented yet, see [P0634R3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) on cppreference.